# Grub setup for fully encrypted Ubuntu and Ubuntu dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, encryption

For compliance reasons (consulting + some norms), I need a dual-boot setup with two separately fully encrypted systems. My main system is an Ubuntu 20.04 and the second system can also be a Ubuntu LTS version. I would like to have it as encrypted and as easy to use as reasonably possible.

I do have a working system with the following partitions:

- sda1 is the EFI system partition
- sda2 contains the /boot for the first Ubuntu
- sda3 contains the LUKS-volume for the first Ubuntu
- sda4 contains the /boot for the second Ubuntu
- sda5 contains the LUKS-volume for the second Ubuntu

The boot is done by grub in the second system which has an entry to chain the grub of the first system.

This setup works, but I have two things I don't really like about it:

a) Can I somehow get rid of the two bootloaders or at least of the chaining setup (it requires two selections during startup)?
b) Is it in any way possible to also encrypt the boot partition? It's not required, but from my perspective would be nice for a "fully encrypted" setup. My understanding is that this is somehow done if I install a standard single-boot fully encrypted Ubuntu.

Does anybody have ideas and pointers how to improve the setup in the ways I would like?